# Update confirmDialog on primefaces

Tags: primefaces

This is my scenario, I've a dataTable populated with clients which has a column with a button that is used to delete the row. When I click on the button it displays the confirmDialog, this confirmDialog has the "message" attribute bind to the name of the client on the backing bean.

I've tried two approaches to update the confirmDialog with the name of the selected row:

1. When I select the row it updates the confirmDialog, the problem with this is that sometimes the time to update is bigger then the time it takes to click on the delete button, it means that the update only happens when the confirmDialog is already opened and there's a bug on primefaces that if you update an opened dialog it closes.
2. Updating the confirmDialog after I click on the delete button, it works if I've selected the row before clicking on the button, but if I click directly on the button, without selecting the row, it updates with the previous selected row instead.

Anyone can think of another strategy to achieve this?

One thing I've thought is to only display the delete button when the row is selected, that way the second approach would work. But I've no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The way i do this most of the time is by making edit or delete in 2 steps. When someone clicks on the delete button you know exactly which row that came from and you save that information. In the dialog you just need to call the delete method and delete the object you saved before.

Let me give you a short example with Cars. First, in your table you call a method to save the current selected Object into "currentCar" and of course open the dialog.

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon ui-icon-close"
   action="#{carBean.prepareRemoveCar(var)}"
   oncomplete="dlg_confirmDeleteCar.show();" />
```

In your dialog you then just need to call the method `public void deleteCar()` and delete "currentCar"

```
public class CarBean implements Serializable {
    ...
    private Car currentCar;
    ...
    public void prepareDeleteCar(Car currentSelectedCar){
        currentCar = currentSelectedCar;
    }

    public void deleteCar(){
        //delete currentCar
    }
    ...
}
```

If you follow this approach, the currently selected row in the table doesn't matter for the deletion. You can click any delete-button and will always delete that row/object, regardless of the selection.

You can of course use this for other cases as well, e.g. updates of your instance, or for the creation of a new instance (for this case you could use a "prepareMethod" to set `currentCar=new Car();`)